# Accidentally installed elementary os boot name, icon and splash screen on Ubuntu 18.04, how can I restore the defaults?

Tags: grub2, package-management, 18.04, icons, elementary

I was trying to install pantheon terminal from the elementary os repository, so I ran an install of `elementary-*` including desktop and icon packages.

One side effect of this is that in the GRUB menu and splash screen all the Ubuntu names and icons have been substituted with elementaryos, for example in the GRUB menu `elementary` and `elementaryos, with linux-kernel 4.15.22` are the default name of the Ubuntu partition. I tried changing the theme and renaming with grub-customizer.

I would like to know if there is a way to completely remove the overwritten elements and restore the Ubuntu default GRUB and boot configuration.

Thanks for any help or tips on this issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand - do you have Ubuntu 18.04 and Elementary both installed on separate partitions?

Comment: Okay, i think i understand that installing an Elementary OS program has added lots of theme changes (including to grub) on your Ubuntu 18.04 installation. Have a look in /etc/grub.d and see if there's a folder there that suggests it's an Elementary Theme. In my case, with a default grub setup, the only folder that says 'theme' anywhere is **05_debian_theme** - I'd suspect you might have another theme there now too. It might be possible to just remove any additional theme you find there, but I'd check the documentation first: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2